# How to get the string after last comma in java?

Tags: java, regex

How do I get the content after the last comma in a string using a regular expression?

Example:

```
abcd,fg;ijkl, cas
```

The output should be `cas`

---

Note: There is a space between last comma and `'c'` character  which also needs to be removed. 
Also the pattern contains only one space after last comma.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*,\\s*(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abcd,fg;ijkl, cas");

if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Outputs:

```
cas
```

---

Or you can use simple `String` methods:

1. `System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(",") + 1).trim());`
2. `System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(", ") + 2));`

Comment: Added regular expression example!

Comment: @dacwe : like the last index, how to get the first index??

Comment: @Deepthi: [`String.indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) does that (but that really is another question).

Answer (score 37):

Perhaps something like:

```
String s = "abcd,fg;ijkl, cas";
String result = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(',') + 1).trim();
```

That is, I take the substring occurring after the last comma and remove surrounding white space afterwards...

Comment: Mind your case! substring instead of subString

Comment: String s = "C:\\Users\\dataset\\Files\\Upload\\samplejpg.jpg";
        String result = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1).trim();                                          
 I used this to extract file name with extension from a path..

Answer (score 15):

Always think of looking for the answer for this sort of question in Apache Commons... the basic ones should probably be included with most builds.  The most appropriate (not using regexes) is this:

```
StringUtils.substringAfterLast(String str, String separator)
```

But if you really want to use a regex for some reason there are a couple of methods which you might want to use, e.g.

```
String removeAll(String text, String regex)
```

or

```
String removeFirst(String text, String regex)
```

Amusingly, you can get what you want by doing this (relying on greedy quantifiers):

```
StringUtils.removeFirst( myString, ".*," );
```

StringUtils is part of apache commons-lang3.

Apart from anything else there is no point re-inventing the wheel.  But I can think of at least 2 other advantages:

1. the Apache people can also be counted on to have developed well tested code dealing with many "gotchas".
2. these Apache methods are usually well named: you don't have to clutter up your code with stoopid utility methods; instead you have a nice clean method which does what it says on the tin...

PS there's nothing to prevent you looking at the source code to check about what the method actually does. Usually they are very easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = " abcd,fg;ijkl, cas";
    String[] words = s.split(",");
    System.out.println(words[words.length-1].trim());
}
```

Comment: Using `split` for this simple search is not optimal. You can use `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: @MohammadDehghan Not optimal it's how many picoseconds? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Only one space:

```
String[] aux = theInputString.split(",\\s");
string result = aux[aux.length-1];
```

0 to n spaces:

```
String[] aux = theInputString.split(",\\s*");
string result = aux[aux.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
String a = "abcd,fg;ijkl, cas";
String[] result = a.split(",[ ]*");
String expectedResult = result[result.length - 1]);
```

Comment: I don't know where you found your wisdom, but based on the JavaDocs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and based on my unit Tests it uses Regular expressions!.

Answer (score 0):

and one more :)

```
String s = "abcd,fg;ijkl, cas";
String result = s.replaceAll(".*, ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answers to solve my problem, it just need to extract the file name from path,

`String s = "C:\\\\Users\\\\Blue Tag\\\\Files\\\\Upload\\\\samplejpg.jpg"; String result = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1).trim();`

Answer (score -1):

```
str.split(",");
```

then

```
str.trim()
```