# Remove string after last occurrence of a character

Tags: java

In my application, I am appending a string to create path to generate a URL. Now I want to remove that appended string on pressing back button.

Suppose this is the string:

```
/String1/String2/String3/String4/String5
```

Now I want a string like this:

```
/String1/String2/String3/String4/
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the string after last comma in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515505/how-to-get-the-string-after-last-comma-in-java)

Comment: i have answered the question ..  over  [here][1]
it is an easy way..

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181969/java-get-last-element-after-split/23075419#23075419

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf()` method for same with

```
if (null != str && str.length() > 0 )
{
    int endIndex = str.lastIndexOf("/");
    if (endIndex != -1)  
    {
        String newstr = str.substring(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am getting index of last occurrence of "/", but how to remove string after that character??

Comment: Thanks Dheeresh. For now, this is fine. I'll ask you if I get any problem.

Comment: This would not work for path already ending with "/", consider this path /user/etc/lib/, be careful when handling such scenario.

Answer (score 49):

```
String whatyouaresearching = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

Comment: "substring", not subString() :)

Comment: @rsan Great answer, since the string whatyouaresearching includes the last "/" it will be more like: `String whatyouaresearching = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.substringBeforeLast](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBeforeLast-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) which is null-safe.

From the javadoc:

```
// The symbol * is used to indicate any input including null.
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(null, *)      = null
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("", *)        = ""
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("abcba", "b") = "abc"
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("abc", "c")   = "ab"
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("a", "a")     = ""
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("a", "z")     = "a"
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("a", null)    = "a"
StringUtils.substringBeforeLast("a", "")      = "a"
```

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Easiest  way is ...**

```
        String path = "http://zareahmer.com/questions/anystring";

        int pos = path.lastIndexOf("/");

        String x =path.substring(pos+1 , path.length()-1);
```

> now `x` has the value **stringAfterlastOccurence**

Answer (score 0):

The third line in Nepster's answer should be

> `String x =path.substring(pos+1 , path.length());`

and not  `String x =path.substring(pos+1 , path.length()-1);` since `substring()` method takes the **end+1 offset** as the second parameter.

Comment: looks like an answer to me