# How to Remove string after second last occurrence of special character?

Tags: java, android, string, stringbuilder

In my application I am trying to make breadcrumbs using StringBuilder

Suppose this is the string :

```
String1>String2>String3>String4>String5>
```

Now I want to remove `String5>` and I want string like this:

```
String1>String2>String3>String4>
```

How can I do this?

**Please help!!**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828313/remove-string-after-last-occurrence-of-character-android-java

Comment: my question is different. please read carefully.. @mandar

Comment: `public StringBuilder delete(int start,int end)`
Removes the characters in a substring of this sequence. The substring begins at the specified start and extends to the character at index end - 1 or to the end of the sequence if no such character exists. If start is equal to end, no changes are made.
Parameters:
`start - The beginning index, inclusive.
end - The ending index, exclusive.`

Answer (score 4):

you can use regex `\\w+>$`

`\\w+` mean match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

`>$` match `>` character where `$` mean at the end

[**Regex Demo Link**](https://regex101.com/r/s4VWin/2)

```
    String s  = "String1>String2>String3>String4>String5>";
    String s2 = s.replaceAll("\\w+>$","");
    System.out.println(s2);
```

Output :

```
String1>String2>String3>String4>
```

Note : To avoid `_` use

```
    String s2 = s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\d]+>$","");
```

---

Just in case if you have data with some special characters like

```
String s = "String1>Stri$#$ng2>String3>Stri#$$#ng4>St$#:/|ring5>";
```

then above solution won't work so you can use

```
    String s2 = s.replaceAll("[^>]+>$","");
    // s2 will be = String1>Stri$#$ng2>String3>Stri#$$#ng4>
```

[**Regex Demo Link**](https://regex101.com/r/s4VWin/3)

`[^>]+` : `^` inside `[]` works as negation mean match everything except `>` character

Answer (score 0):

Split string by > and then apply for loop on the array. match string by position. if match then delete otherwise add to new stringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of lastIndexOf and substring().

Example:

```
String oldValue = "String1>String2>String3>String4>String5>";
int lastIndex = oldValue.lastIndexOf('>', oldValue.length() - 2);
String newValue = oldValue.substring(0, lastIndex + 1);
```