# How to remove every thing after last comma character in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

With JavaScript, how can I remove every thing after last coma character in a string using regular expressions?

For example if i input `Vettucaud, Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala, India`,last word `India` should be removed and the output need tro be like `Vettucaud, Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala`

Exactly the reverse thing in

- [How to get the string after last comma in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515505/how-to-get-the-string-after-last-comma-in-java)
- [get all characters after “,” character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058923/get-all-characters-after-character)

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? Or could you just do `str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(",") - 1);`?

Comment: @jonhopkins I know that lastIndex way, I want to do it with regex

Comment: @jonhopkins Why the "-1"? That would trim one more character before the last comma. Shouldn't it be `str = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(","))`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple:

```
str = str.replace(/,[^,]+$/, "")
```