# Split the URL of YouTube coming from JSON

Tags: android, youtube

I want to display thumbnails of YouTube videos. URL of videos are retrieved from JSON.

List of these URLs is stored in **vm.getVideo_url()**.

I am splitting URL to get id of URL and by passing id I want to get thumbnail.

By clicking on a particular thumbnail I want to redirect to YouTube.

```
                    public class ImageAdapters extends BaseAdapter
                     {
                         private Context context;
                         private long enqueue;
                         ArrayList<Video_Items> vs_list;
                         ImageAdapters(Context c,ArrayList<Video_Items> vs_list)
                         {
                         context=c;
                         this.vs_list=vs_list;
                         }
                         public int getCount()
                         {
                             return vs_list.size();
                         }
                         public Object getItem(int pos)
                         {
                             return pos;
                         }
                         public long getItemId(int pos)
                         {
                             return pos;
                         }

                        @Override
                        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
                             final ImageView imageview=new ImageView(context);
                             imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                             imageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150,120));

                             String s=vm.getVideo_url();
                             String[] string=vm.getVideo_url().split("embed/");
                             System.out.println("Tokens : "+s);
                             String url_id="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/"+s+"/hqdefault.jpg";
                             Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url_id).into(imageview);

                            imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
                                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(vm.getVideo_url()));  
                                    startActivity(intent);  

                                }
                            });
                             return imageview;
                        }
```

URL is not splitting and thumbnail are not generated.

How to redirect with this?

Comment: post one full url example to see if you require a split or a cut

Comment: Here is URL .."video_url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/PGatzxZx7u8",

Comment: I want to split it from "embed/"

Comment: so its best if you remove everything  before the last slash  -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515505/how-to-get-the-string-after-last-comma-in-java

Comment: "List of these URLs is stored in vm.getVideo_url()." This is wrong, according to the comment under my answer. So please share only useful and not misleading information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong object. Instead use it like this:

```
String s=vm.getVideo_url();
String[] string=vm.getVideo_url().split("embed/");
System.out.println("Tokens : " + string[0] + " and youtube id = " + string[1]);
String url_id="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/"+string[1]+"/hqdefault.jpg";
```

The difference is in using **string[1]** as the container for the youtube id, instead of **s**, that simply contains the complete url.

Comment: It retrieves only last URL from the list of URLs from JSON. I want all the URLs from JSON.

Comment: Then it is easier to help if you post the content of vm.getVideo_url().

Comment: I have created a class named **Video_Items** and its object is vm.public String getVideo_url() {
  return video_url;
 }
 public void setVideo_url(String video_url) {
  this.video_url = video_url;
 } and setting it using JSON like this for(int i=0; i<jarray.length();i++)
      {
       JSONObject jm=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
       vm=new Video_Items();
       vm.setVideo_name(jm.getString("video_name"));
       vm.setVideo_url(jm.getString("video_url"));
       video_list.add(vm);
      }

Comment: length of **vm.getVideo_url()** shows last URL only. Can I use **ArrayList<Video_Items> vs_list** ? As its size is same as numer of URLs I am having in JSON.

Comment: `vm` is only one item, but I see you are adding each item to `video_list`. I don't know where you use `vs_list`, so I don't know if it is fine to use it. But `video_list` seems ok to be used for this. You need to iterate over `video_list` and split each item from this list, and then store the result maybe in a String[], where you will have a lot of `url_id`s. In order to help you more, please post the needed source code, by updating your question.